# knowrob json_prolog problems

Tags: ros, json-prolog, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have got the following errors when I use knowrob/json_prolog.

I tried the examples as in the tutorial:

$ rosrun json_prolog json_prolog package_name(tried several)

---

ERROR: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/process.pl:47:
'$open_shared_object'/3: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/i386/process.so: undefined symbol: Sfilefunctions
Warning: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/process.pl:47:
Goal (directive) failed: process:use_foreign_library(foreign(process))
ERROR: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/process.pl:334:
Exported procedure process:process_wait/3 is not defined
ERROR: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/process.pl:334:
Exported procedure process:process_kill/2 is not defined

---

I am using Ubuntu 11.04, Ros electric, installed using apt from the online repository.

Is there any compatibility issue of the swi-prolog with json_prolog/jpl etc?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11578/knowrob-json_prolog-problems/) by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

this has been a problem with the SWI Prolog libraries: They are regularly renamed from libpl.so to libswipl.so and back...

It should be fixed in the svn version, can you please verify that it works for you? Then I'll start the release as .deb packages.

Thanks
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2